# Solving the equation:$ x= 1+\omega^x+ \omega^{2x}$

Tags: problem-solving, roots-of-unity

> Solve for $x$:
>   $$
> x = 1+ \omega^x + \omega^{2x}
> $$

Tried factorizing by completing the square, but have no idea how to proceed

Comment: Perchance is the order of the root of unity given? Also is $x$ assumed to be real or what?

Comment: X is assumed to be real and no other info is given which is mind boggling